# 'let' and variables in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm a newbie in Haskell and I'm reading "Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!".

An expression that defines with a "name" and a "space", followed by "parameters" could be used as functions.
Consider the following code:

```
doubleMe = 2
```

this code actually follows the rule above, so we could see it as a **function**. but it really seems like an **assign** operations in java or c++.

So, How to understand the variable in Haskell?

Comment: you need to work out what doubleme really is,  you've used the word variable....  why?

Comment: Are you writing a Haskell program (.hs file) or using ghci? In ghci you need let, in a normal source file you don't.

Comment: Also I can't tell whether you're asking "what's the difference between a variable and a function?" or whether you're asking "what's the difference between using 'let' and not using 'let'?"

Comment: `doubleMe` is not a function, as a function must have arguments. See also: http://conal.net/blog/posts/everything-is-a-function-in-haskell

Comment: @immibis GHC 8 made `let` optional in GHCi at the top level.

Answer (score 8):

At the top level of a program, `name = expression` is a *definition*. It creates a variable, in the sense of a mathematical variable—just a name for some expression. It can be a definition of a value:

```
two :: Int
two = 2
```

Or a definition of a function:

```
twice :: Int -> Int
twice x = x * two
```

A definition refers to a function if its type has a function arrow `->`.

In a `do` block or GHCi, `let name = expression` is a *local definition*.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let greet name = "Hello, " ++ name ++ "!"
  putStrLn (greet "world")
```

Finally, there is another use of the `let` keyword: `let name = expression1 in expression2`. This creates a variable local to a single expression:

```
length (let x = "hello" in x ++ x)  ==  10
```

Be aware that `let` takes a *block* of bindings, so it’s subject to the layout rules like other layout keywords, such as `do`, `where`, `of` as in `case`…`of`, and so on:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do

  -- Bindings must be aligned past the start column.
  --  ↓
  let greeting name = "Hello, " ++ name ++ "!"
      parting name = "Goodbye, " ++ name ++ "!"

  putStrLn (greeting "world")
  putStrLn (parting "world")
```

```
length $ let x = "hello"
             y = "goodbye"
  in x ++ y
```

As with other layout keywords, can instead put a newline and a fixed amount of indentation after `let`, and then not worry about alignment:

```
main = do              -- ← newline+indent
  let                  -- ← newline+indent
    greeting name = …
    parting name = …
  …
```

```
length $ let
  x = "hello"
  y = "goodbye"
  in x ++ y
```

Or you can always include explicit curly braces and semicolons:

```
main :: IO ();
main = do {
  let {
    greeting name = "Hello, " ++ name ++ "!";
    parting name = "Goodbye, " ++ name ++ "!";
  };
  putStrLn (greeting "world");
  putStrLn (parting "world");
};
```

```
length $ let {
    x = "hello";
    y = "goodbye";
  } in x ++ y
```

Comment: Note the `let` in a `do` block is just syntactic sugar for a nested `do` block: `do let foo = ...; ...` is the same as `do let foo = ... in do ...`.